# Search for Power Meter with pyvisa library? (Python 3.10)

Tags: python, pyvisa

I'm attempting to connect to and read from a ThorLabs PM100D power meter via the [`pyvisa` Python library](https://pyvisa.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). I'm using Python 3.10.

I'm able to connect to and read from the power meter using [ThorLabs' power meter monitor software](https://www.thorlabs.com/software_pages/ViewSoftwarePage.cfm?Code=OPM) without any issues. According to the documentation of the power meter monitor software, the device should be accessible via the Python library.

The first thing I wanted to try to do was to simply search for the device while it's connected to my system, and to see whether I can find and identify it.

I wrote the first few lines, which simply searches for and lists all supposedly available devices:

```
import pyvisa

def main():
    rm = pyvisa.ResourceManager()
    resources = rm.list_resources()
    print(resources)

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    main()
```

However, I'm getting an empty list of devices from the script above, even with the power meter connected and switched on.

I did some research, and figured out that the `list_resources` function of the `ResourceManager` class of `pyvisa` works by providing it a "search term" as an argument.

According to the ThorLabs documentation, the appropriate search term for the PM100x power meter series would be `"USB?*::0x1313::0x807?::?*::INSTR"`. However, that also results in no devices listed.

I also tried to specify the specific USB COM port that the power meter is connected to in the search term, to no avail.

What am I missing here? Is my search term incorrect?

Thanks for reading my post, any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Do you still have the ThorLabs software running when you try this code?  It's generally not possible for more than one program to talk to a COM port at one time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux, it can be because Python does not have the ability to read the USB port.

On Ubuntu, you need to add your user to the dial out group. Try this:

```bash
sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER
```